# linux: search for files of type *.php recently modified

Tags: linux, find

How do I adapt this to return recursively files of only extension *.php?  thx!

```
find . -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Add `-name '*.php'`:

```
find . -type f  -name '*.php' -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort
```

Note that since the expression is evaluated by `find` from left to right you must specify the `-name` test before the `-printf` action.

See [this manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for details about tests, actions and how find evaluates your expression.

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type f -name '*.php' -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td %TT %p\n' | sort
```

You can find more options in the [manfile of `find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find).

Comment: `-name` should be specified before `-printf`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use

```
find . -type f -mtime -n -name '*.php' | sort
```

where n is the number of days a file exists. For example

```
find . -type f -mtime -1 -name '*.php' | sort
```

should return all files that are less than a day old. That is useful if you want to filter you results.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation**: Use unix command find with `-type` flag and regex for `.php` end of file and `-ctime` for creation time

The find utility recursively descends the directory tree for each path listed, evaluating an expression (composed of the 'primaries' and 'operands') in terms of each file in the tree.

**Solution:** `find . -name "*\.php" -type f -mtime -4w` - which means in my current directory find all the php combination names in type file that were created in the last 4 weeks.

**Extra Reading**: According to **documentation**

```
 -type t
         True if the file is of the specified type.  Possible file types are as fol-
         lows:

         b       block special
         c       character special
         d       directory
         f       regular file
         l       symbolic link
         p       FIFO
         s       socket

 -mtime n[smhdw]
         If no units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference
         between the file last modification time and the time find was started,
         rounded up to the next full 24-hour period, is n 24-hour periods.

         If units are specified, this primary evaluates to true if the difference
         between the file last modification time and the time find was started is
         exactly n units.  Please refer to the -atime primary description for informa-
         tion on supported time units.
```